# Passing localstorage value to Server (Java, JSP)

Tags: java, javascript, jsp, servlets

im currently creating a canvas Javascript game and im passing localstorage variable to my database which is the Score. Score being 'elapsed'. When i was debugging i saw that the localstorage value is there. But it just doesnt seem to store into the database. Preferably without the use of Ajax?

```
function drawElapsedTime(){
        var elapsed=parseInt((new Date() - startTime)/1000);
        g.save();
        g.beginPath();
        g.fillStyle="#008000";
        g.font="14px Verdana"
        // draw the running time at half opacity
        g.globalAlpha=0.50;
        g.fillText(elapsed+" secs",canvas.width-75,25);
        localStorage.setItem("score",elapsed);
        g.restore();

    }
 var storedTime = localStorage.getItem("score");

 <form action="UserActionServlet" method="post">


                 <input type="submit" value="scoreObj" class="submit" />

     </form>
```

Command:

```
String xscore = request.getParameter("score");

        int score = 0;
        if (xscore != null) {
            score = Integer.parseInt(xscore);
        }
 System.out.println(xscore);
```

Answer (score 0):

You are not passing the score variable as a parameter in your form post.

```
<form action="UserActionServlet" method="post" onSubmit="submitForm(this.form)">
        <input type = "hidden" name = "score"/>
        <input type="submit" value="scoreObj" class="submit" />
</form>

<script>
    function submitForm(f){
         f.score.value = storedTime ;
         f.submit();
    }
</script>
```